# How do I parse complex json object in Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have following property which I need to parse as JSON. I tried to use `parse_json()` but it does not work

Query

```
AzureActivity
| where OperationNameValue == "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write" 
| where ActivityStatus  == "Started"
| where (Properties contains "8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635") or (Properties contains "b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c")
| extend request = parse_json(Properties)
| where request.requestbody.Properties.Scope == "/subscriptions/6f5c5be9-a2dd-49c9-bfa1-77d4db790171"
```

Raw data which needs to be parsed

> { "requestbody":
>   "{\"Id\":\"992a2739-9bd2-4d04-bc5f-5ed1142b9861\",\"Properties\":{\"PrincipalId\":\"5ac319a4-740b-4f09-9fd3-fce3ce91fedf\",\"RoleDefinitionId\":\"/subscriptions/6f5c5be9-a2dd-49c9-bfa1-77d4db790171/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635\",\"Scope\":\"/subscriptions/6f5c5be9-a2dd-49c9-bfa1-77d4db790171\"}}"
>   }

Comment: Had to do `where Properties contains @'\"Scope\":\"/subscriptions/6f5c5be9-a2dd-49c9-bfa1-77d4db790171\"'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have a look at the bottom of [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction) (also quoted below), which explains why the following works (BTW, note that I've [replaced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/datatypes-string-operators#understanding-string-terms) `contains` with `has` for you, from an efficiency standpoint):

```
AzureActivity
| where OperationNameValue == "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write" 
| where ActivityStatus  == "Started"
| where (Properties has "8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635") or (Properties has "b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c")
| extend request = parse_json(tostring(parse_json(Properties).requestbody))
| project request.Properties.Scope
```

> It is somewhat common to have a JSON string describing a property bag in which one of the "slots" is another JSON string.
>
> For example:
> `let d='{"a":123, "b":"{\\"c\\":456}"}'; print d`
>
> In such cases, it is not only necessary to invoke parse_json twice, but also to make sure that in the second call, tostring will be used. Otherwise, the second call to parse_json will simply pass-on the input to the output as-is, because its declared type is dynamic:
>
> `let d='{"a":123, "b":"{\\"c\\":456}"}'; print d_b_c=parse_json(tostring(parse_json(d).b)).c`

Comment: Wow, what a mess. I expected parser to be smarter then that like other .NET parsers do.